# Escape analysis for class instances

Tags: javascript, v8

Does v8 do escape analysis for class instances, or is there some fundamental roadblock, which makes this excessively harder than for objects? In an example:

```
class P {
  x;
  y;
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  add(other) {
    return new P(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
  }
  multiply(s) {
    return new P(this.x * s, this.y * s);
  }
}

const f = (a, b) => a.add(b).multiply(5).x;
// These allocations -^^^^^^-^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Are temporary instances allocated here, and is this avoidable? It is a simplified example for a naive vector implementation.

---

Following are checks i did, which make me suspect a difference in the first place. I am moderately new to the topic, and also not too proficient in asm. It is likely I made some silly mistake. Comparing the following, I see that the resulting code:

- with plain objects, is considerably shorter, and has only one multiplication (expected)
- exchanging with class instances, is around four times as long (just for the function `f`), and has two multiplications

  ```
  vmulsd xmm1,xmm1,xmm2
  -- no jumps here --
  vmulsd xmm0,xmm0,xmm2
  ```

  and to my naive eyes looks like everything is being allocated.

(put in snippets to collapse)

```js
const add = (p1, p2) => ({ x: p1.x + p2.x, y: p1.y + p2.y });
const multiply = (p1, s) => ({ x: p1.x * s, y: p1.y * s });

const f = (a, b) => multiply(add(a, b), 5).x;

const rnd = () => Math.random() * 1000000;
const rndP = () => ({ x: rnd(), y: rnd() });

%PrepareFunctionForOptimization(f);
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) f(rndP(), rndP());
%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(f);
f(rndP(), rndP());
```

```js
class P {
  x;
  y;
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

const add = (p1, p2) => new P(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y);
const multiply = (p1, s) => new P(p1.x * s, p1.y * s);

const f = (a, b) => multiply(add(a, b), 5).x;

const rnd = () => Math.random() * 1000000;
const rndP = () => new P(rnd(), rnd());

%PrepareFunctionForOptimization(f);
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) f(rndP(), rndP());
%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(f);
f(rndP(), rndP());
```

`node --allow-natives-syntax --print-opt-code --code-comments class.js > classAsm.txt`
(not on the newest node, but unless something changed in a recent v8 update, it shouldn't matter)

This in itself doesn't prove anything, and i am not proficient enough in the topic to understand the full code, especially with all the ICs etc I already have trouble identifying. I am aware that for most applications, the allocations are likely not going to pose a bottleneck, especially as they will be gen0 for GC. I am simply curious, to push my understanding of the topic, in case it does eventually matter.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. A JS class is (basically, though not entirely) syntactic sugar around a function with a prototype. Returning raw objects, with no constructor and no prototype chain, is significantly "easier" (fewer operations). The two JS examples you give are very different solutions that accomplish similar ends.

Comment: Well, my understanding must be wrong somewhere. Either there is a fundamental roadblock, which I do not see, or a mistake in my analysis of the resulting asm. Inlining a `new P(/*...*/)` instead of a `{/*...*/}` is different, but to me looks conceptually similar. In my mind, once an inline cache is established, a class instance should be no different than a "raw object". It might be, that the link between the constructor arguments going directly to the properties isn't noticed. However, as it is such a common case, I'd have thought there would be some handling for it.

Comment: PS: a take-away of "when things are performance-critical, always prefer object-literal-factories over classes" would be rather sad. `class` is imho syntactic sugar to write a template for simple objects, and it then being significantly inferior performance-wise, would be unfortunate.

Comment: As an attempt to get more insights about the "link from constructor to properties" (again in my naive understanding), `const proto = { /*add, multiply*/ }; const P = (x, y) => { const o = Object.create(proto); o.x = x; o.y = y; return o; };` doesn't show the same problem. I think i am missing some elephant in the room.

Comment: I made no general claims about plain objects over classes. If you have a class composed solely of properties, then calling a constructor would usually be more expensive than just returning a plain object. However, if you start adding functions to that class, then inheritance is going to have major advantages over redefining the same methods over and over. There is no one-size-fits-all solution. Performance-critical code must always be analyzed within its unique situation.

Comment: Creating an instance of a class has overhead, as you must associate the new object with it's prototype and make a callout to the constructor which is a separate function. Your comment "_exchanging with class instances, is around four times as long_" makes sense because calling a constructor does _more_ than just create an object, so needs more operations to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does v8 do escape analysis for class instances

Yes.

> Are temporary instances allocated here

No.

> with class instances, [the code] has two multiplications

I see only one (for `x`; the operations on `y` are all dead-code-eliminated).

(This is with recent V8; I haven't checked older versions.)

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I assumed this didn't change for a while. For unfortunate reasons, I am on V8 8.6.395.17 (node 15) - perhaps that shot me in the foot here. It was easier than setting up d8, and i am not aware of a way to do it with chrome. Perhaps my understanding of asm is also the issue here, and a misinterpretation caused me worrying.